# Managing a database connection object in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm working with a Postgresql database with Django. Because of licensing reasons, I can't use `psycopg2` , so I'm using the alternative `pygresql`.

I don't need to use the Django ORM at all, I simply need the cursor for `cur.execute()` and `cur.fetchall()`.

Since I can't use the pygresql `pgdb` module in the Database settings in `settings.py`; I've to manually open up a connection object.

What would be the best practice to do this? Currently I've simply created the connection object `conn=pgdb.connect(params)` in `views.py` outside of all functions, but this seems a bit hacky.

Any tips?

Comment: oh man, you are not going to taste the beauty of django then.

Comment: I know right. Sadly there doesn't seem to be any other option for me.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a good idea to create your own `PYGRE_CONFIG` dictionary in `settings.py` that has info about the server hostname, database name, login name etc. You can use it by using `from django.conf import settings` and `settings.PYGRE_CONFIG`.  Then, create a separate application `utils` or `pygre` in the root of your project directory that manages the connection object (opening and closing it as needed using `settings.PYGRE_CONFIG`) and stores it in a [thread-local variable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.local). Your other applications can import things from this module. Keeping it as a separate app can make it easy for you to port it from project to project.

Comment: ` (opening and closing it as needed using settings.PYGRE_CONFIG) and stores it in a thread-local variable. ` : So the connection 'open' would have to be triggered when a request is received. How would I go about doing this? And when would I close it? A brief explanation or an example would be brilliant!